# ImportError: No module named queue - python3

Tags: python

i need to import the queue module for my project, using python3.

One month ago everything worked as it should do, but today, as i tried to run the code again, i got the error **"ImportError: No module named queue"**.

I've already read some posts to this topic and tried things like `import queue as Queue`, but this also doesn't work...same error as before.

Comment: Are you using Pycharm?

Comment: No it's the Parrot Olympe Shell in a Linux Ubuntu Environment.

Comment: Maybe you uninstalled it or you forgot to activate venv if you have one.

Comment: I suspect you're not actually running python3 like you think. You could try other modules, though. What about `from asyncio import Queue`?

Comment: No , i dont have a virtuellenv

Comment: ImportError: No Module named asyncio

Comment: Are you sure you're using python 3 instead of 2?

Comment: Hard to guess without a very good crystal ball, because of too little information... I would try 1. you have broken your Python installation - solution install it again. Or 2. You have more than one Python installation, and the default has changed - so you no longer use the same Python.